# Powershell: Backgrounding command causes it not to work

Tags: powershell, background, command, external

My script stores a bunch of External application commands from an app like so

$app1 = get-command "C:\Where\Command\Located.exe"

Then I call it with

& $app1 -S -P 9000

(where -S -P and 9000 are parameters as I'd pass them in a cmd.exe shell).  Up to here everything works perfectly.  However, I want to run this as a background task and here's where I begin running into trouble.

Start-Job -ScriptBlock { & $app1 -S -P 9000 }

fails with "The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an invalid object."  I've searched google for about two days and everything I've tried seems to be for naught.  Enclosing parameters in @() and trying to splat them out, Invoke-Expression, Invoke-Command, Invoke-Item (still unclear as to what these are all doing).  I've also tried converting the whole command to a string and then calling Invoke-Expression within the start job but it doesn't seem to be working either.  So this question is resources to understand when all these things are appropriate to use and why it doesn't work as soon as I pass it to a background job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the `$app1` variable to the script block:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($app1) & $app1 -S -P 9000 } -ArgumentList $app1
```

Note that instead of

```
$app1 = get-command "C:\Where\Command\Located.exe"
```

you can also just have

```
$app1 = "C:\Where\Command\Located.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great!  Do you recommend passing locations of external commands through strings rather than through the get-command object?

Comment: @clanahan - When you have the path and you can run the command with that, it makes sense to just run with that than get-command and use that command right? Not 100% sure, but I don't think Get-Command is intended for that kind of usage.

Comment: Ahhh, I wasn't sure as I thought the object would be preferable.  The string was does work better.